# Proof of period of $f(ax+b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have been taught that $f(x)$ is called a periodic function with period $T$ if $$f(x)=f(x+T)$$
This I understand completely. Also I have been taught that $$f(ax)=f(ax+T/|a|)$$
if $f(x)$ has a period $T$.
I am able to understand this but I am not able to prove this algebraically or graphically. Any help?

Comment: Thanks for my wasted time. Please be more careful.

Comment: @Aditya: So you proved the wrong thing, and then edited the question to agree with what you proved, right?

Comment: That was not a typo, I misunderstood the concept entirely.

Comment: Let me rollback the edit, then.

Answer (score 1):

Not the standard proof but anyways:
For a more general case:
Let:
$$f(ax+b)=f(ax+b+T)=f(a(x+\underbrace{T/a}_{T_0})+b)$$
Then period is $T/|a|$
since it must be $\ge0$

Comment: @TonyK I did'nt notice the OP posted a typo

Comment: @TonyK this is something like $\sin x$ has period $2\pi$ then $\sin 2x$ has period $\frac{2\pi}{|2|}=\pi$

Comment: @Aditya: I don't think it was a typo, I think it was a genuine misunderstanding.

Comment: @TonyK yeah I was getting it wrong all the way. It was not a typo.

Comment: @TonyK I was taught this property and I well remember it: "If $f$ is a periodic function with period T then $f(ax+b)$ is a periodic function with period $T/|a|$"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have it a bit muddled. If $f(x)=f(x+T)$ for all $x$, then if we substitute $ax$ for $a$ we get that $f(ax)$ is equal to $f(ax+T)$, not $f\left(ax+\dfrac{T}{|a|}\right)$.

I think what you have in mind is this:
Let $g$ be the function defined by $g(x)=f(ax)$. Then $g(x) = g\left(x+\dfrac{T}{|a|}\right)$ for all $x$.

Note that $g\left(x+\dfrac{T}{|a|}\right)$ is not the same as $f\left(ax+\dfrac{T}{|a|}\right)$.

Comment: how is $g(x) = g\left(x+\dfrac{T}{|a|}\right)$ ?